# Framework recommendation for interactive multitouch application

Tags: sdk, 2d, interactive, touchscreen, motion

We are currently developing a multitouch multiuser application which runs on a big touchscreen table.
Obviously the application has a lot of animations and transformations included, i.e. moving and rotating UI elements around using touch gestures, menu opening animations, touch rotations etc.

To better understand what kind of Application this is going to be, here is a Video of a similar application with kind of the behaviour we are targeting (minutes 0:16 - 0:27): https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=13&v=qIOR9FiL97w

Back in the days we used Adobe Flash for such applications, since it was the only way of getting good performance and interactivity but since flash is dead, what is the current best way of implementing such an application?
We tried game engines like Unreal Engine 4 and Unity but the support for multitouch is very meager and most of the gestures etc. have to be implemented yourself and also most of the common controls like scrollviews, carousel controls etc.

We also tried UWP which has good touchscreen support and implements most of gestures and behaviour you are expecting of a touchscreen application and almost all common user controls are already implemented but we got a huge problem regarding performance, especially on higher resolutions like 4K or 8K. The more controls and grids and layout we put in, the slower the application became and moving around and rotation etc. are very slow and only run on one thread. We had a look into the new Composition API but its very complicated and its not very clear whats the best way to combine XAML controls and composition API, also there is Win2D but it only provies basic functionality like drawing rectangles and also no touchscreen support, only through XAML.

So, is there any good Framework or API to implement applications like in the video I linked? Or is Flash still the best way? Is there a Qt library for such things or even Javascript? Or is even Android the way?

Answer (score 2):

https://kivy.org

Kivy - Open source Python library for rapid development of applications
that make use of innovative user interfaces, such as multi-touch apps.

Cross platform, GPU Accelerated, comes with more than 20 widgets, all highly extensible.

Comment: looking good so far. sadly I have almost no experience in python. I have found https://www.noesisengine.com but it seems to have the same problem as WPF and UWP, its not designed to move/update objects every frame but using keyframe animations etc, thats not suitable for our case.